# Load All Method Results in Python Class to Dictionary

Tags: python, class, dictionary, methods

If I have a class like that below (in reality, it has a lot more methods), and I want to load each method's results into a dictionary, is there a faster way to do `features_to_dict`, that's also modular if I add new methods?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class CraigsPage():

    def __init__(self, page_file):
        self._page = open(page_file).read()
        self.soup = BeautifulSoup(self._page)
        self.title = self.soup.title.string
        self.body = str(self.soup.find('section', id='postingbody'))

    def get_title_char_count(self):
        return len(list(self.title.replace(' ', '')))

    def get_title_word_count(self):
        return len(self.title.split())

    def get_body_char_count(self):
        return len(list(self.body.replace(' ', '')))

    def features_to_dict(self):
        feature_dict = {}
        feature_dict['title_char_count'] = self.get_title_char_count()
        feature_dict['title_word_count'] = self.get_title_word_count()
        feature_dict['body_char_count'] = self.get_body_char_count()
        return feature_dict
```

Comment: Dont use get_ getters. Use properties. https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property

Comment: That's interesting. I didn't know about those. Any way to automatically load all of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.getmembers) module is handy for this sort of stuff:

```
def features_to_dict(self):
    members = inspect.getmembers(self, inspect.ismethod)
    return {name: method() for name, method in members if name.startswith('get')}
```

Answer (score 1):

Python classes have [`__dict__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy) attribute, that stores all attributes for the class as a dictionary. The following snippet iterates over `__dict__` trying to find functions beginning with `get`, and automatically runs them, storing the results to a dict:

```
class A(object):
    def get_a(self):
        return 1

    def get_b(self):
        return 2

    def features_to_dict(self):
        self.d = {}
        for f_name, f in A.__dict__.iteritems():
            if 'get' in f_name:
                self.d[f_name[4:]] = f(self)
a = A()
a.features_to_dict()
print a.d
```

This returns `{'a': 1, 'b': 2}`.

Answer (score 1):

Use dir() method instead of **dict** attribute.

```
class A(object):
    def method(self):
        return 123
    def call_all(self):
        skip = dir(object) + ['call_all']
        results = {}
        for key in dir(self):
            if key not in skip and callable(getattr(self, key)):
                try:
                    results[key] = getattr(self, key)()
                except Exception as e:
                    results[key] = e
        return results
```

Comment: What is the advantage of dir() over dict?

Comment: Class's `__dict__` contains only attributes of that class, not inherited attributes. Function `dir` returns list of all attributes, including inherited. So, this variant works also for all descendants of this class.

Comment: I see. Is there a risk that it would call methods I'm not aware of?

Comment: Thanks. So you feel that one will accomplish the same thing?

Answer (score -1):

Kinda simple approach, to not use introspection at all and explicitly define which methods to call:

```
class A(object):
    methods_to_call = [
        "get_title_char_count",
        "get_title_word_count",
        "get_body_char_count",
    ]
    ...
    def features_to_dict(self):
        feature_dict = {}
        for method in self.methods_to_call:
            feature_dict[method[4:]] = getattr(self, method)()

        return feature_dict
```

Comment: This is not modularizable at all, though, and would need to be updated every time a method is added